# React Navigation Drawer Navigator overwrite onBackdropPress or onClose listener?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I need to run a certain function when the drawer shows itself and then another function when the drawer hides.

I can make it so that the only way the drawer opens is through me calling this.props.navigation.openDrawer(), and I can almost do the same thing for closing, except that when you press on the backdrop of the drawer, it closes. I need to either find a way to overwrite/disable that behavior of pressing on the backdrop closing the drawer. Or I need a listener that will listen for the drawer closing event.

Using React Navigation v3.

I'm using my own contentComponent and on that component I already tried using the 'willFocus' and 'willBlur' events like this but they don't seem to work:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.willFocusListener = this.props.navigation.addListener(
      'willFocus',
      this.setStatusBarColorDrawerOpen
    );

    this.willBlurListener = this.props.navigation.addListener(
      'willBlur',
      this.setStatusBarColorDrawerClose
    );
  }

  setStatusBarColorDrawerOpen = () => {
    console.log(' setting StatusBar to GRAY! ');
    if (Platform.OS !== 'ios') StatusBar.setBackgroundColor('rgb(242,242,242)');
  };

  setStatusBarColorDrawerClose = () => {
    console.log(' setting StatusBar to WHITE! ');
    if (Platform.OS !== 'ios') StatusBar.setBackgroundColor('#FFF');
  };

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.willFocusListener.remove();
    this.willBlurListener.remove();
  }
```

Any other ideas?